# scala - Resultset to spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, resultset

i am querying mysql table

```
val url = "jdbc:mysql://XXX-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/pg_partner"
val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
val username = "XXX"
val password = "XXX"
var connection:Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
val statement = connection.createStatement()
val patnerName = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id,name FROM partner")
```

i do get my result in `patnerName` but i need to be converted to Dataframe.

i am able to print data by below code:

```
while (patnerName.next) {
  val id = patnerName.getString("id")
  val name = patnerName.getString("name")
  println("id = %s, name = %s".format(id,name))
}
```

Now How do i convert `patnerName` to a DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about directly using the Spark functionality?

```
val jdbcDF = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://XXX-XX-XXX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/")
  .option("dbtable", "pg_partner")
  .option("user", "XXX")
  .option("password", "XXX")
  .load()
```

The code is taken from [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases).

Comment: what does `spark` in `spark.read` refer to? is it sparkcontext or sqlcontext

Comment: It is [SparkSession](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html) that appeared in Spark 2. Which Spark version are you using?

Comment: i am using spark 2.0.0 i am using these in my code: 

  `val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("QuaterlyAudit").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)` sc is not working i know `sc` is sparkcontext but what is `SparkSession`

Comment: The same code I got error: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Answer (score 5):

So you'll have to do it in several steps:

1. Define your columns and prepare a schema

```scala
    val columns = Seq("id", "name")
    val schema = StructType(List(
      StructField("id", StringType, nullable = true),
      StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true)
    ))
```

2. Define how you will convert each record in the ResultSet to a Row at each iteration

```scala
    def parseResultSet(rs: ResultSet): Row = {
      val resultSetRecord = columns.map(c => rs.getString(c))
      Row(resultSetRecord:_*)
    }
```

3. Define a function to convert your ResultSet to an Iterator[Row]. It will use the function you defined in the previous step (when you call it in the next step).

```scala
    def resultSetToIter(rs: ResultSet)(f: ResultSet => Row): Iterator[Row] =
      new Iterator[Row] {
        def hasNext: Boolean = rs.next()
        def next(): Row = f(rs)
      }
```

4. Define a function that creates an RDD out of an Iterator[Row].toSeq which uses the functions you defined in the previous step. Use the schema to create a DataFrame from the RDD

```scala
    def parallelizeResultSet(rs: ResultSet, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
      val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(resultSetToIter(rs)(parseResultSet).toSeq)
      spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema) // use the schema you defined in step 1
    }
```

5. Finally call your function

```scala
    val df: DataFrame = parallelizeResultSet(patner, spark)
```

Comment: I tried the approach mentioned above I am able to create dataframe but it is creating empty dataframe for me dosnt have the data from my result set.

Comment: @Saurabh are you able to verify that the ResultSet contains any data at all? Try to `rs.next()` and then select a column from the current row with `rs.getString("col_name")` and see if it returns you data.

Comment: Yes I verified that I am having data in my resultset using rs.getString("col_name")..It has created the dataframe with e structure I have provided.